# Reverse url problem: template url is giving reverse error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am getting this error Reverse for 'video_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['video/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']. Please help..

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('video/<slug:slug>/', views.VideoDetail.as_view(), name='video_detail'),
]

#views.py
class VideoDetail(DetailView):
    model = Video
    template_name = 'video.html'

# index.html
 <a href="{% url 'video_detail' video.slug  %}">

#models.py
class Video(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
   year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=3)
   genres = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   poster = models.URLField(default='')
   plot = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   trailer = models.URLField(default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.urls import reverse

    return reverse("video.html", kwargs={"slug": str(self.slug)})
```

#urls.py main site

```
urlpatterns = [
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
path("", include("accounts.urls")),
path("", include("blog.urls")),
path("", include("video.urls")),
]
```

#views.py rendering index.html

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
template_name = 'index.html'
```

Comment: No, that will be VideoDetail view

Comment: I am not trying to link any video here.. I want an url  path('video/<slug:slug>/', views.VideoDetail.as_view(), name='video_detail'),  with a views.py VideoDetail that will redirect me to video.html webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put a link in your index template `<a href="{% url 'video_detail' video.slug %}">`. But in the `HomePage` view, you don't set `video` anywhere. That means that `video.slug` evaluates to the empty string `''`, which explains the `with arguments '('',)'` part of the error message.

You could fix the problem by changing `video.slug` to the name of the video that you want to link to, e.g.

```
<a href="{% url 'video_detail' 'name-of-title' %}">
```

If you want to use `video.slug` instead of `'name-of-title'` in your template, then you need to add `video` to the template context. For example, you could do:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['video'] = get_object_or_404(Video, slug='name-of-title')
        return context
```

Then in index.html you can do `<a href="{% url 'video_detail' video.slug %}">`.

Or, you could add *all* videos to the template context.

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['videos'] = Video.objects.all()
        return context
```

Then you can loop through the videos in your template.

```
{% for video in videos %}
<a href="{% url 'video_detail' video.slug %}">{{ video.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It should be `**kwargs` instead of `**context`. I've fixed the examples above.

Comment: Change it to `return context`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and informative comments. For now I can move forward in my project....

Answer (score 0):

use -

```
<a href="{% url 'video_detail' slug=video.slug  %}">
```

make sure `video` is model object where you are using it otherwise it will give nothing and you will get url error.

Comment: Still getting error = Reverse for 'video_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['video/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Comment: @noob it's getting nothing with `video.slug` I already mentioned that `video` should be a model object, you can post your view from which you are reading this template

Comment: Please check if I am making some mistake here.

Comment: @noob in which template your are using - ` <a href="{% url 'video_detail' video.slug  %}">` and from which view you are rendering this template

Comment: I am using index.html and with anchor tag redirecting it to video.html..

Comment: views.py provided in above code to view the template

Comment: I am talking about `index.html`... post the view which is rendering `index.html` and also post `index.html`

Comment: @noob what do you think from where template is getting `video` object so that you are directly using `video.slug` you have to pass this from `HomePage` view but you are simply rending a template how do template engine know what actually `video` is ? learn how things are working, open docs

Comment: But when I manual enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/video/name-of-the-title/     it renders the video.html